# Whats "Replace Event For Transaction With Id " in my vugen CodeGenerationLog.txt, and why have I got > 8 of them

Tags: loadrunner

Whats "Replace Event For Transaction With Id " in my vugen CodeGenerationLog.txt, and why have I got more than 8 identical occurrences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just something internal we write to the log. No need to act upon it.